# problem with unmet dependencies while installing sqlite3

Tags: dependencies

while installing sqlite3 in ubuntu 16.04 LTS, i can see the following errors due to unmet dependencies, please help me in solving this.

```
sudo apt install sqlite3
[sudo] password for dharani: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sqlite3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sqlite3' has no installation candidate
```

**If apt-search is performed it is giving the following result.**

```
dharani@chikki:~$ apt search sqlite3
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
akonadi-backend-sqlite/xenial 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu6 amd64
  SQLite storage backend for Akonadi    

slang-sqlite/xenial 0.4.0-3.1 amd64
  S-Lang bindings to the sqlite3 database library

sputnik/xenial,xenial 12.06.27-2 all
  Extensible wiki

sqlcipher/xenial 3.2.0-1.1 amd64
  Command line interface for SQLCipher

sqlite3-pcre/xenial 0~git20070120091816+4229ecc-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Perl-compatible regular expression support for SQLite

sqliteman/xenial 1.2.2-0ubuntu9 amd64
  GUI tool for SQLite3 admin and developers alike

sqliteman-doc/xenial,xenial 1.2.2-0ubuntu9 all
  GUI tool for SQLite3 admin and developers alike   

dharani@chikki:~$
```

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt install -f`, `sudo apt update`, then finally `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir, but it is still showing errors.  When i type" sudo apt-get install sqlite3",it is showing the following errors :    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sqlite3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sqlite3' has no installation candidate
Please help me sir

Comment: Lets search for `sqlite3` it aught to be there, do that with `apt search sqlite3` and give the result. Perhaps there a repo missing from your install

Comment: Only a part of the output is shown because of limited size of the comment.dharani@chikki:~$ apt search sqlite3
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
akonadi-backend-sqlite/xenial 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu6 amd64
  SQLite storage backend for Akonadi

aolserver4-nssqlite3/xenial 0.9-2build1 amd64
  AOLserver 4 module: module for accessing SQLite 3 databases

bacula-common-sqlite3/xenial 7.0.5+dfsg-4build1 amd64
  network backup service - SQLite v3 common files

bacula-common-sqlite3-dbg/xenial 7.0.5+dfsg-4build1 amd64
  network backup service - SQLite v3 common files (debugging)

Comment: It's there, try `sudo apt install sqlite3` NOTE the `apt` not `apt-get`

Comment: I tried sudo apt install sqlite3. It is giving the same error.    E: Package 'sqlite3' has no installation candidate

Comment: Please post the former result into your post so I can read it then check that  `main` repo is enabled in you `system settings` top right corner of your desktop

Comment: I included the result  of apt search sqlite3 in my post(i have edited the post),please have a look at it.

Comment: It's not there please check your  `system settings` in the `software & updates` section and in `Ubuntu software` please make sure `main repo` is enabled. check and let me know

Comment: Thank you so much sir...!! .I think now sqlite3 is installed.When i type sqlite3 --version ,it is giving the following output                                       
 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24 3d862f207e3adc00f78066799ac5a8c282430a5f.

Comment: How was it done was it done?